# Automatically split line at intersection of nearby shapes/zones

Tags: qgis, buffer

I have a large dataset in QGIS with roads (blue line in picture below) and 3 type of zones (mostly rectangular areas, red and green shape in picture below). My task is to spilt to road into segments when there is an intersection between the zones nearby (see picture, yellow line). The problem is, that the zones do not touch the road.

[image: Example image with one road and to zones]

I tried to go at this by creating buffers around the zones that are large enough so that they meet/touch the road and then cut at overlapping segments. The problem is, that the buffers of the zones also overlap. Therefore more segments than desired are created. These can be joined of course but because of the buffers, the resulting segments never intersect at the desired location (which is of utmost importance).

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this task?